# Deleting a node from a double linked list in java

Tags: java, linked-list

Hello I have a double linked list set up, and i have a search working for it and all that stuff, i just want to delete from it too.

For my search i have:

```
public void firstNameSearch(String name)
{
    Node u = header;
    while (u != null && u.list() != name )
    {
        System.out.println("Searching List...");
            u = u.getNext();
    }
    if (u.list() == name)
    {
        // what do I need to put here to delete it

    } 
}
```

I have looked through over post on stack overflow, but the ones i found were in C, so weren't a great help, I understand the concept on how to make it delete the node, just can't get it functional.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  What didn't work? Did you try debugging it in a debugger? This is much the same in C++ or C# as it is in Java.  Have you looked at the code for LinkedList as its is a doubly linked list? c.f. `LinkedList.unlink(Node)`

Comment: The `u.list() == name` and `u.list() != name` almost certainly don't do what you want. Use `String.equals()` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a very basic operation.I assume there is method as set/getPrevious() as its a double linked list.

```
[previous]<==>[u]<==>[next]
```

Deleting an element in a  doubly linked list would be [simply changing the references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list#Removing_a_node) pointers of previous and next node.

```
if (u.list() == name)
    {
        Node pre = u.getPrevious();
        Node next= u.getNext();

        //Connect next node and previous node
        if(pre != null){
          next.setPrevious(pre);
        }else{
         header=next; 
        }

     //Connect previous node and next node
        if(next != null){
          pre.setNext(next);
        }else{
          pre.setNext(null); 
        }




    }
```